# Fixed text in Input type

Tags: php, html

i Want the txnid and amount to be static and uneditable in the input type. Amount should be uneditable and fixed to 10000 and txnid should be the one random generated but it should also remain unchanged.

```
<table>
    <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
    <tr><td>txnid</td><td><input type="text" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>amount</td><td><div class="amount"><input type="text" name="amount" value="" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: use `disable="true"`  in input tag, Or else why you need to set those here just generate that random value where you are submitting the form.

Comment: Bad advice. Disabled inputs aren't counted when using POST or GET.

Comment: Sidenote: (and I've said this 3 times already today), `<form>` CANNOT be child of `<table>`.

Comment: the amount need not to be changed it should be fixed

Comment: If the amount should be fixed, and the user should have absolutely no control over it, stop putting it in the form - store it server-side, and use that value.

Comment: seems like this question holds deeper secrets than we've been told about

Answer (score 1):

Use `readonly` on the inputs. Just remember that all it takes to change it is a little meddling in the source code in any modern browser.

Example: `<input type="text" value="something" readonly>`

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Added an example. If that was what you mean by elaborate. If you're talking about the "modern browsers" thing, it just means you have no control of the output to a browser. I can change whatever I want, before submitting the form, `readonly` or not.